# How to solve a quintic congruence equation?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, congruences

My textbook has this quadratic equation that I have to solve, any ideas how I could show that?

$$15 | (21n^5+10n^3+14n),\;\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: @Bill: Because I think that is a better direction, the other containing more.  I think I read that SE fixed it so there can't be new duplicate circuits, so once one is closed as duplicate the other will be blocked I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.**

Solve separately  modulo $3$ and modulo $5$, then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve simultaneous congruences.

B.t.w., this is not a quadrattic congruence, but a quintic one.